# Reference request Riesz Functional Calculus

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, banach-spaces

I am faithful to Conway's book: A Course in Functional Analysis, for learning functional analysis, but the Chapter VII, $\S$4 on Riesz Functional Calculus, has a lot of gaps. I really want to understand the topic and need to be on the same lines as Conway. Can anyone suggest any other detailed text or notes for the same?

Comment: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~lwmarcou/notes/pmath810.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjNksLF_Z_2AhWGrosKHeDZAVkQFnoECC0QAQ&usg=AOvVaw1Xd_pnLeD7qYl-fiARpt9L

Comment: @BazyliZuczek Yea thanks I found them already. They are good notes.

Comment: @BazyliZuczek But still every where else Riesz functional calculus is done around smooth Contours, but Conway  does them around rectifiable curves.

Comment: Is that so crucial ? The result $f(a)$ for an element in the Banach algebra for any function $f$ holomorpic in a neighborhood of $\sigma(a)$ does not depend on the choice of the curve in the defining integral. So limiting to convenient contours seems reasonable.